# Facebook wall downloader

Tags: linux, download-manager, facebook, unix

I'm looking for software/app which allow me to download/export Facebook wall from certain periods into common formats such as HTML, PDF, or similar. So after export, I can open the files and scroll the links without logging-in to Facebook (aka off-line browser of the wall with all the thumbnails and links).

It should work with Linux or macOS.